# Embedding python code on an interactive map

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a highly interactive map for the user. Not only an interactive map in the sense of visualization, where the user can move, zoom and click on the map to see a tooltip appear. But also where the user can for example click on an area (a polygon) and a python method is executed to cut the area into squares. A way to **integrate the execution of python code** in the map according to the user's interactions.

Is there a python solution to do this ? A tool or a specific library.

Comment: You can use [Folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/).

Comment: Thanks @KadirŞahbaz, but are you sure we can add click event (as a function to execute) with Folium? Could you give me an example? I did not see that this was explicitly possible in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I didn't see  it was possible in the documentation, too. You can also check **Ipyleaflet** library.

Comment: Indeed at first glance Ipyleaflet seems to allow this. Thanks again !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, **[ipyleaflet](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet)** seems to be the best soltion to meet your needs at the moment. You can read [documentation](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

It includes some classes which have useful events for you as follows:

- Map (on_interaction)
- Layer (on_click, on_dblclick, on_mousedown, on_mouseup, on_mouseover, on_mouseout)
- Marker (on_move)
- GeoJSON (on_click, on_hover)